# Python Asyncio: Am I Awaiting too much?

Tags: python-asyncio

I've been grokking some of my sample async code and I'm struggling to understand the flow of the data and how often I find myself awaiting.

Am I using await correctly?  Also - are my output types correct?  I'd imagine some these should be outputting coroutines (but my Pyright/Pylance type hinting keeps telling me that's wrong...)

The functions that require inspection are governed requests, send, governed_send, and governed_sendall.  Maybe I'm not understanding what await is doing completely - and how this interacts with function scopes.

The code works correctly; I'd like to understand why and whether I can optimize out some of these awaits or if that's unnecessary.

```py
import time
import asyncio
import httpx

from typing import Any, Callable, Coroutine, Dict, List
from rich import print


class GovernedClient:

    def __init__(self):
        self.client = httpx.AsyncClient()
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.semaphore = asyncio.BoundedSemaphore(4)

    def __del__(self) -> None:
        # Define a destructor that closes the client and the loop.  
        async def close(self: GovernedClient) -> None:
            # An async function is required to await aclose
            await self.client.aclose()
        self.loop.run_until_complete(close(self))
        self.loop.close()

    def govern_requests(fn: Callable) -> Callable:
        # govern_requests applies semaphore locking to a given callable.  
        async def call(self, *args, **kwargs):
            async with self.semaphore:
                return await fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return call

    async def send(self, method: str, url: str) -> httpx.Response:
        # A single send.  
        request = httpx.Request(method, url, headers={'accept': 'application/json'})
        return await self.client.send(request)

    @govern_requests
    async def governed_send(self, method: str, url: str) -> httpx.Response:
        # Applies semaphore locking via decorator.  
        return await self.send(method, url)

    def governed_sendall(self, urls: List[str]) -> List[httpx.Response]:

        async def goverened_sendall(urls: List[str]) -> List[httpx.Response]:
            start = time.time()
            awaitables = [self.governed_send('GET', url) for url in urls]
            responses = []
            for response in asyncio.as_completed(awaitables):
                responses.append(await response)
                print('Total time: ', int(1000 * (time.time() - start)))
            return responses

        return self.loop.run_until_complete(goverened_sendall(urls))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    URL = 'https://www.icanhazdadjoke.com'
    bc = GovernedClient()
    urls = [URL for url in range(20)]
    responses = bc.governed_sendall(urls)
    for response in responses:
        print(response.json())
```

Comment: Yeah,  what confuses me I guess are the types and tracing them.  For instance, governed send retirns an awaited response but is this a response or a coroutine or both?  How does await affecr types?  When that awaited function is invoked before syncronization, what type is it?  Isnt its return type a future?  In writing this I had to experiment with await placement there were one or two cases where I accidentally synced my  web calls

Answer (score 1):

You know that async is a function that will not block the code. Right?
You know that await is an async function caller that when called it will not block the code. Right?
So There's no *using too much async/await* because if you using it it will not blocking your code unlike def and functioname().
I guess you may understand.
Happy day!